# How to write system of differential equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

I need help in writing this system in LaTeX:

[image: how to write this in latex]

**EDIT:** I need more help because I am still unable to use the provided solution. My system is:

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\begin{eqnarray}  
  \begin{rcases}
    \frac{d\phi_{1}(t)}{dt}&= -\phi_{1}(t)-c_{1}\phi_{3}(t),\\
    \frac{d\phi_{2}(t)}{dt}&= \alpha_{1}\phi_{3}(t)-(d_{1}+\mu_{1})\phi_{2}(t),\\ \nonumber
    \frac{d\phi_{3}(t)}{dt}&= \mu_{1}\phi_{2}(t)-d_1 \phi_{3}(t)-c_{2}\phi_3(t) \tilde{z_2}(t),\\ \nonumber
    \frac{d\phi_{4}(t)}{dt}&= \alpha_{2}\phi_{3}(t)\tilde{z_2}(t)-(d_2 + \mu_2) \phi_{4}(t),\\ \nonumber
    \frac{d\phi_{5}(t)}{dt}&= \mu_{2}\phi_{4}(t)-d_{2}\phi_{5}(t),\\ \nonumber
    \end{rcases}
\end{eqnarray}
\\
\begin{eqnarray}
    \begin{rcases}
            \phi_{1}(t^+)&=\phi_{1}(t),\nonumber \\
            \phi_{2}(t^+)&=\phi_{2}(t),\nonumber \\
            \phi_{3}(t^+)&=(1-\delta) \phi_{3}(t),\nonumber \\
            \phi_{4}(t^+)&=\phi_{4}(t),\nonumber \\
            \phi_{5}(t^+)&=\phi_{5}(t).\nonumber
            \end{rcases}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{empheq}
```

Comment: Hi amit. Welcome to the site. Does Maarten's link answer your question?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The duplicate candidate does not explain the issue with the equation numbers or the alignment of the right curly braces.

Comment: I agree with Heiko. the duplicate does not cover the eqn numbers. The solution I provided below does.

Comment: Drop the eqnarray!!!!

Comment: then how to write math things?

Answer (score 7):

`empheq` and `mathtools` to the rescue

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{empheq,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
  \begin{rcases}
    ax+by=c \\
    ax + by =c
  \end{rcases}
  \\
  \begin{rcases}
    x(0)=x0 \\
    y(0)=y0
  \end{rcases}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear thanks for the reply, i need your more help because i am still unable to use it, actually my system is:

Comment: @amitsharma, never ever use `eqnarray`, see http://tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/madsen.html. `empheq` is already using `align` so adding `eqnarray` does not make sense.

Comment: great it works......now  only problem is that lower part aligned to right side...how to align it to left?

Comment: You can add a `&` in front of the `\begion{rcases}`, but then the `}` no longer aligns. If you need it left aligned and the `}`'s aligned, you will probably have to recreate `rcases` your self using something similar to `\left.\begin{array}{@{} p{some length}  @{}} ... \end{array}\right\}` (untested)

Comment: Thanks for great help Dear. I need your more help regarding that i need equation number only once for the system in center.

Comment: Then there is no need to use `empheq`, just replace the `empheq` env (and its options) with `cases` and wrap all that inside an `equation`